Alternative to setting self.__class__ to something else?
What's the right way to add a method to any member of a set of sibling instances (i.e. each instance's class inherits from a common base class)?
The siblings come from fsspec and are out of my control, but it's like this.
class Base:
    def open(self): pass
    def read(self): pass

class A(Base):
    def read(self): pass

class B(Base):
    def read(self): pass

There could be a C and some plugin might add a D ... these are out of my control. All my code gets is an instance of some subclass of Base.
My code gets an instance and needs to hand it off to another library expecting an instance of a class inheriting from Base. But I want this instance to have a new feature (not something that would be of general utility outside my code, so no changes to fsspec). In code, something like this.
with fsspec.open(...) as f: # f is an instance of `A`, `B`, etc.
    g = dunno_what(f) # asking about this part
    dataset = xarray.open_dataset(g) # handing off to xarray

Now xarray is going to behave differently depending on what g implements, and requires g to be an instance of Base.
The way I see it, my feature would come as a method of a mixin.
class Mixin:
    def feature(self): pass

Then the following appears to achieve my goals but has lots of drawbacks.
for Item in (A, B):
    # `item` is the `f` in the minimal example above
    item = Item()
    # here's what I've tried, but is advised against
    item.__class__ = type("Item", (item.__class__, Mixin), {})
    # it works though ...
    assert isinstance(item, Base)
    assert item.open.__func__ is Base.open
    assert item.read.__func__ is Item.read
    assert item.feature.__func__ is Mixin.feature

Assigning to item.__class__ is not for novices, so I am interested in the suggested alternatives given by abarnert (third one is outside of my control):

"Use a factory to create an instance of the appropriate class dynamically, instead of creating a base instance and then munging it into a derived one."
"Use __new__ or other mechanisms to hook the construction."

I can't think of how to do either one while still achieving the goals given above as assertions. Thank you for showing me the way!

Please provide a code example of how your code "gets this instance" and how it would "hand it off to another library". You seem to mixing up classes and instances in the question and it's unclear what you're trying to achieve (or what you have tried to get it to work)

What's wrong with just monkeypatching your feature onto Base? That seems a lot simpler than these alternatives.

@wim Dunno, maybe nothing? How would that be done? Could be an acceptable answer!

Maybe it is, but something smells off - you say you "add another feature" and then hand off an instance to another library. But how is the other library aware of your "feature"? Who is the consumer of the new feature? What is the new feature, is it a new method like the example shows, or are you trying to modify the behavior of an existing method/attribute?

@Grismar Do the edits help?

if you are going to do something like this, you can just monkeypath the Base class.

@juanpa.arrivillaga The way you say that makes me think it's a distasteful practice, lolz. But if its the right way can you show me? I would be guessing what it means.

Base.whatever = feature given some function def feature(self): ...

It is code smell, I would say, but I think it is a better approach that modifying .__class__ which is playing with black magic

@juanpa.arrivillaga Monkey-patching the base class affects all its instances. I think the OP is looking for a per-instance solution.

@blhsing What makes you think the OP is looking for a per-instance solution? I don't see that in the question, nor the comments. It says "a method to any member of a set of sibling instances" which even hints otherwise.

You can create a proxy object for the given item and mixin class with Base as the base class such that the proxy object would delegate attribute lookups to the item and then to the mixin class as a fallback:
def add_mixin(item, mixin):
    class _Proxy(Base):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            try:
                return getattr(item, name)
            except AttributeError:
                return getattr(mixin, name).__get__(item)
    return _Proxy()

for Item in (A, B):
    item = Item()
    item = add_mixin(item, Mixin)
    assert isinstance(item, Base)
    assert item.open.__func__ is Base.open
    assert item.read.__func__ is Item.read
    assert item.feature.__func__ is Mixin.feature

Demo: https://ideone.com/JVRzyO
Note that the factory function above dynamically creates a class with the item and the mixin in a closure for each item, which incurs a higher overhead.
A leaner approach would be to use a proxy class whose constructor takes an item and a mixin class, though the resulting code would be somewhat less readable because the instance variables can't be accessed with the dot operator but with the __dict__ attribute, which itself has to be obtained by calling object.__attribute__ instead:
class Proxy(Base):
    def __init__(self, item, mixin):
        self.item = item
        self.mixin = mixin
 
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(
                item := object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')['item'], name
            )
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(
                object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')['mixin'], name
            ).__get__(item)
 
for Item in (A, B):
    item = Item()
    item = Proxy(item, Mixin)
    assert isinstance(item, Base)
    assert item.open.__func__ is Base.open
    assert item.read.__func__ is Item.read
    assert item.feature.__func__ is Mixin.feature

Demo: https://ideone.com/eiyV2j
As suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga though, this approach can be made more readable while minimizing the potential of name collision by making the instance variables of the proxy class "private" through the protection of name mangling with a prefix of double underscores:
class Proxy(Base):
    def __init__(self, item, mixin):
        self.__item = item
        self.__mixin = mixin
 
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__item, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.__mixin, name).__get__(name)

for Item in (A, B):
    item = Item()
    item = Proxy(item, Mixin)
    assert isinstance(item, Base)
    assert item.open.__func__ is Base.open
    assert item.read.__func__ is Item.read
    assert item.feature.__func__ is Mixin.feature
    assert item.__Proxy_item is item
    assert item.__Proxy_mixin is Mixin

Demo: https://ideone.com/OJ42Ge

why recreated the _Proxy class each time? Just create it once, have it take the instance it proxies to as an argument.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Using a closure helps avoid the ugly code of calling object.__getattribute__ to obtain the __dict__ attribute, which would otherwise look like: https://ideone.com/eiyV2j

While you don't need to make every class a flywheel, and I might agree that using object.__getattribute__ is a bit ugly, I think using object.__getattribute__ inside of a __getattribute__ implementation is one particularly appropriate place to do it, and anyway, mere ugliness wouldn't justify adding a kilobyte overhead to each instance, at least, it should be noted that this is happening

@juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, I've noted the readability vs. overhead trade-off then.

ahhh I see why you though this was too ugly, but you should just implement __getattr__ instead, in there, just use getattr(self.item, name) etc

@juanpa.arrivillaga But with __getattr__ it won't be a true proxy object. item.item and item.mixin for example would access attributes of the proxy itself instead of those of the underlying item. Demo: https://ideone.com/jD11Rv

that's fine, name them self.__mixin and self.__item to prevent name collisions.

@blhsing Thanks a lot for both cases. It works for me. I'm wondering if there is an intermediate between per-instance and once that has the simplicity of the per-instance class without the overhead. If the loop was for item in (A, B, A, A, B, B, A) and we had a factory to get just two proxies. Anyway, accepting your answer for the working solution and inspiration thanks!

@juanpa.arrivillaga True. I've updated my answer to include this suggestion then. Thanks. Ian should find it to be the sweet spot he's looking for.

This is ridiculously overcomplicated compared to a monkeypatch, and a monkeypatch has not been ruled out as acceptable by anything in the questions or comments as far as I can see.
